# Como conseguir o Valor resultado de DIV divValor. result[2] na controller do mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, mvc

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnSend").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("VerificaCep","ConsultaCep")',
                type: "GET",
                contentType:"application/json",
                data: { cep: $("#txtCep").val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#divValor").html("<label>Endereço:" + result[0] + "   Bairro:" + result[1] + "  Cidade:" + result[2] + "  Estado:" + result[3] + " </label>")
                },

                error: function(xhr, exception){
                    alert("Favor digitar o CEP!")
                }
            });

        });
        var Valor = document.getElementById('divValor.result[2]').innerHTML;
    });
```

Comment: O script funciona corretamente, só não consigo pegar o resultado da Array[2] para a Controller pois irei fazer uma pesquisa por cidade do cliente. Desculpem a pergunta mas tentei de tudo e nada. Desde ja muito obrigado

Comment: Não seria apenas, adicionar no data? Ficando `data: { cep: $("#txtCep").val(),divvalor: $('#divValor').text() },` ou algo assim?

Answer (score 0):

2 erros:
Primeiro que nao existe a div com a id = `divValor.result[2]`, voce esta usado label para todos os valores.
Segundo erro `result[n]` precisa estar dentro da funcao `success: function (result)`

```
var Valor;
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnSend").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("VerificaCep","ConsultaCep")',
                type: "GET",
                contentType:"application/json",
                data: { cep: $("#txtCep").val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#divValor").html("<label>Endereço:" + result[0] + "   Bairro:" + result[1] + "  Cidade:" + result[2] + "  Estado:" + result[3] + " </label>");
                    valor = result[2];
                    console.log(valor);
                },

                error: function(xhr, exception){
                    alert("Favor digitar o CEP!")
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: Perfeito Hudson, valor recebe  o índice correto, como posso agora chamá o valor na Controller? Muito obrigado

Comment: voce ja esta chamando pelo metodo get, agora se vocer que enviar alguma coisa para o seu controler vc pode usar o metodo post